# What if I have a voltage between ground neutral?

Tags: ground

What does it mean when there is voltage between ground and neutral (220V) and between phase and neutral (220V) but no voltage between phase and ground (0V)?

What could happen? Is it safe?

Is it normal that when I plug in a lamp, it works just fine?

Comment: Everyone I think ignores the most basic question: what country are you in? Is it common practice in that country to have polarized outlets, where the location of phase and neutral is known? How do you know that what you think of as "phase" is really supposed to be phase - what reference are you using to make this determination? It's impossible to answer your question without knowing all that.

Comment: For example, in Europe, there's generally no expectation that the L and N pins on an IEC C13 plug are actually polarized as such. The equipment must operate properly no matter which of the two pins the L and N actually fall on. Of course the PE pin has only one location.

Answer (score 4):

Actually, it sounds like your phase and neutral are swapped. This is shown by seeing full voltage between neutral and ground but no voltage between phase and ground.

If you have non-grounded appliances, such as lamps, you will potentially have lethal voltage on the metal case.

I recommend calling an electrician immediately and not using the circuit until it has been checked.

Answer (score 1):

What you have is a floating ground. Yes, this is a potentially lethal problem, and you should get it checked out and fixed by someone that knows what they're doing.

Answer (score 0):

Let’s take the case that you are in a front of a wall socket and all cables are with the same colour: which is the live, which is the neutral and which is the ground connector??

We assume that your circuit it is equipped with an ECLB (Earth Leakage Circuit Breaker).

-Recognize the live conductor: the easiest way is to use the special screwdriver with a neon lamp. Or try all the possible combinations with conductors with your AC voltmeter. You will conclude with two conductor that your meter reads zero volt. OK the remain conductor is the live.

-Recognize the earth and neutral conductors: Use an appropriate tungsten lamp more than 60W. Then connect one lead with the live and the other test the other two remain connectors. The neutral conductor is the one that is no action by ECLB. If ECLB acts this conductor is the earth and consequently the other is the neutral